# Trying to understand the usage of multidimension dynamic fields in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to learn C at the moment and have encountered a task I cannot solve on my own. This is a simple minesweeper implementation.

Short description what the program should do:
It gets the input files via the command line, opens them one at the time, creates the minesweeper field for each and if multiple files are opened the program saves them formatted in one file. I don't want to format them one beneath the other, I want to use a dynamic two dimensional array, so that the matrix expands without losing the already saved mines.

Each input file has the same build:

```
3\t5\n
0\t3\n
3\t7\n
...
```

The first line always indicates the size of the n x m matrix and all following lines are the coordinates of the mines.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct game{
    int n;
    int field[];
}game;


int read_files(char **input, int length);
int make_field(char *input, int i, int *ptr);
void increment(int i, int j, game);
int is_inside_bounds(int i, int j, game);
void free_field();
void safe_field();


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    read_files(argv, argc);
    return 0;
} 



//read_files reads all files given to the programm via the commandline

int read_files(char **input, int length){
    int i= 1; 
    char string[20];              //input goes into this via fgets
    int filecount = 0;            //counts the amount of files
    int fieldptr[100];           // is an int array with the purpose of memorizing the size of all gamefields I create
    int j = 0;

    for (; i< length-1; i++){
        FILE *in;
        if(!(in = fopen(input[i], "r"))){
            fprintf(stderr, "File not found.\n"); 
            err = 2;
            return err;
        }
        while (fgets(string,20,in)){ 

            make_field(string, filecount, fieldptr); //gives all relevan info to the make_field function
            j++;
        }
        fclose(in);
        filecount++;
    }
    return 0;
}



int make_field(char *string, int file, int *fieldptr){
    struct g = NULL;//this is my problem
    int g.field = NULL;//this too
    char delimiter[] = "\t\n";     //the input file cuts the chars with \n and \t
    char *ptr;                     //needed for strtok
    file= file * 2;               //this is used for the filehandling
    ptr = strtok(string, delimiter);
    int a = atoi(ptr);           //cast to int so I have the gamefield size as a int
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    int b = atoi(ptr);       //cast to int so I have the gamefield size as a int


    if (fieldptr[file] == 0 && file == 0){//init field
        fieldptr[0] = a; //memorize first call
        fieldptr [1] = b;
        g.field = malloc(a * sizeof(int*));
        if (NULL == field){
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
            return 3;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < a; j++){
            g.field[j] = malloc(b * sizeof(int));
            if(NULL==g.field[j]){ allocated
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }else if (fieldptr[file] == 0 && file != 0){ //if it is the first line and but not the first file
        field = realloc(g.field, a * sizeof(int*));
        if (NULL == field){
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
            return 3;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < a; j++){
            field[j] = realloc(field[j], b * sizeof(int));
            if(NULL==g.field[j])
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }
        fieldptr[file] = a;      //filehandling memory
        fieldptr[file+1] = b;

    }else if(fieldptr[file] != 0 && file == 0){    //fill the mines +indicators into the array
        g.field[a][b] = -1;
        int m;
        for (m = -1; m <= 1; m++) {
            int n;
            for (n = -1; n <= 1; n++) {
                increment(a + m, (fieldptr[file+b]) + n, g);
            }
        }

    }else if (fieldptr[file] != 0 && file != 0){     //fill the mines +indicators into the bigger array
        g.field[a][fieldptr[file+b]] = -1;

        int m;
        for (m = -1; m <= 1; m++) {
            int n;
            for (n = -1; n <= 1; n++) {
                increment(a + m, (fieldptr[file+b]) + n, g);
            }
        }
    }
    return field; //not sure about the return yet
}



void increment(int i, int j, game *g) {       //increments the neighbours of the minefield
    if (is_inside_bounds(i, j, g) && field[i][j] != -1) {
        ++g.field[i][j];
    }
}

int is_inside_bounds(int i, int j, game *g) {         //checks if the access of increment is inside the array
    int nLines = sizeof(g.field) / sizeof(g.field[0][0]);
    int nColumns = sizeof(g.field[0]) / sizeof(field[0][0]);
    return i >= 0 && i < nLines && j >=0 && j < nColumns;
}
```

Coming from java, in my eyes this should work, but I really don't get how C works with multidim arrays. Can anybody point me into the right direction?

EDIT:

gcc has following output:

```
error: invalid use of flexible array member
   g.field = realloc(g.field, a * sizeof(int*));

In function ‘increment’:
note: the ABI of passing struct with a flexible array member has changed in GCC 4.4
 void increment(int i, int j, game g) {
```

So my problem is that I don't really know how to declare and use the array the right way.

Comment: What is the problem? You mention what you want it to do, but not what it is doing.

Comment: Your code makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. You should probably start with a simpler exercise. If you have questions about a *minimal* example, you have much better odds of getting useful answers.

Comment: Does `typedef struct game{
    int n;
    int field[];
}game;` compile without error for you?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @chux, `int field[]` is a flexible array member, valid since C99

Comment: @Trey added my problem

Comment: @Alter Yes a flexible array member.  I was incorrectly thinking about restrictions with VLA.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct g = NULL;//this is my problem
int g.field = NULL;//this too
```

You are right, this is your problem

1) You mean `game g` instead of `struct g`

2) You can not use `NULL` without a pointer:

```
game *g = NULL; /* Ok */
```

3) You can not access a member (`g.field`) of an uninitialized `struct` (`g`)

More problems:

```
g.field = malloc(a * sizeof(int*));
```

You can not use `malloc` with the flexible array member, you need to reserve space for the whole `struct` including the size of the flexible array member:

```
game *g = malloc(sizeof(*g) + (n * sizeof(int)));
```

or better yet

```
game *g = malloc(sizeof(*g) + (n * sizeof(g->field[0])));
```

Note `sizeof(int)` instead of `sizeof(int *)`, you want to reserve space for `n` `int`s not for n pointers to `int`s

or change `field` to

```
typedef struct game {
    int n;
    int *field;
} game;
```

in order to use `malloc` with the member directly.

Comment: According to the definition of `struct game`, trying to assign to `g.field` is incorrect regardless of the argument to `malloc()`.

Comment: Recommend `g.field = malloc(sizeof *(g.field) * a);`  Avoid getting the type wrong.

Comment: @EOF, you are right, I forget the flexible array, edited, thanks!.

Comment: @chux, as pointed by EOF, you can not use `malloc` with the flexible array member, you need to reserve space for the whole `struct` including the size of the flexible array member

Comment: Right you are.  Yet in that case suggest  `malloc(sizeof *g +  n * sizeof g.field[0]);`